# keycloak admin-cli login with OTP

Tags: docker, keycloak, google-authenticator, totp

I'm currently using keycloak 15.0.1 [keycloak container](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker) and i'm trying to configure the TOTP authentication (google authenticator) for the admin account in the default master realm. For this question purpose, i'll be using a local container.

The config is applied correctly when logging in from the web UI, but the problem is when using the admin-cli

I'm using the following command to log in the admin-cli:

```
sh ./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin --client admin-cli --password <my_password>
```

This works fine without the OTP setup, but when OTP is turned on, i'm getting the following error:

```
17:23:26,837 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-9) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=admin-cli, userId=94468ce6-a5b2-4b90-a993-476583f5e05e, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=admin, authSessionParentId=88f1c289-f9b7-4267-833a-084ccac99816, authSessionTabId=7HBaV7p3DhA
```

I've tried adding some params in case it would accept it:

- --totp=
- --otp=
- -totp=
- -otp=

It did not work, i've searched in keycloak documentation but i couldn't find anywhere on how to do it.

Has anybody tried and successfully connected to the admin-cli when using TOTP?

Comment: HI @Cedrik, Did u find any solution for your problem?

Comment: I did not find a solution to that spceific problem, i decided on using a service account and using API calls instead of using the CLI. It's a patch but not a fix.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question, super relevant, as OTP can be a security requirement in many systems